# How to recieve file path from Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my app I have a textedit that holds the path to the file my app is to process. I have a browse button so the user can choose the file. After choosing the textedit should containbthe path/file information.
In the button's onClick method I have the following code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT ); 
 intent.setType ( "*/*" );
 startActivity ( Intent.createChooser ( intent, "Select a file" ) );
```

How do I get the Uri after the user is done?

Comment: I did read it. I wrote my question as clearly as I could.

Comment: Check this --> http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/04/more-for-pick-file-using.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startActivityForResult()` per [dev guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters), recommended at the top of the [Android docs on Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)

> Starting an activity
>
> An Activity represents a single screen in an app. You can start a new instance of an > Activity by passing an Intent to startActivity(). The Intent describes the activity to start and carries any necessary data.
>
> If you want to receive a result from the activity when it finishes, call startActivityForResult(). Your activity receives the result as a separate Intent object in your activity's onActivityResult() callback. For more information, see the Activities guide.

Comment: Ok! That (and Swati's link) set me on what I hope is the right path. I am getting data, now to use it.

Comment: Thanks! It seemed you just needed a little push to get unstuck.  Please/feel free to edit my answer with whatever you find for that `onActivityResult()` callback... if you can stand to!

Answer (score 1):

My final code, works for my needs

```
    public void btnPress_onClick ( View v )
  {
   Intent intent = new Intent ( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );
    switch ( v.getId ( ) )
      {
        case R.id.btnFilesystem:
          setContentView ( R.layout.filesystem );
          txtFileSource = findViewById ( R.id.txtboxSourcePath );
          txtFileDest = findViewById ( R.id.txtboxDestPath );
          break;
        case R.id.btnTextEdit:
          setContentView ( R.layout.textedit );
          textBox = findViewById ( R.id.textEditField );
          break;
        case R.id.btnHelp:
          setContentView ( R.layout.help );
          break;
        case R.id.btnSecurity:
          setContentView ( R.layout.security );
          spnrPivotTable = findViewById ( R.id.spnrSelectPivotTable );
          showKey = findViewById ( R.id.chkShowKey );
          passKey = findViewById ( R.id.txtPassKey );
          break;
        case R.id.btnHome:
          setContentView ( R.layout.main );
          break;
        case R.id.btnBrowseSource: 
          intent.setType ( "*/*" );
          startActivityForResult ( Intent.createChooser ( intent, "Select a file" ), BROWSE_SOURCE );

          break;
        case R.id.btnBrowseDest:
          intent.setType ( "*/*" );
          startActivityForResult ( Intent.createChooser ( intent, "Select a file" ), BROWSE_DEST );
          break;
        default:
          FancyToast.makeText ( MainActivity.this, "Function not yet coded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.INFO, true ).show ( ); 
      }
  }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data )
  {
    switch ( requestCode )
      {
        case BROWSE_SOURCE:
          if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK )
            {
              txtFileSource.setText ( data.getData ( ).getPath ( ) );
            } else
            {
              FancyToast.makeText ( MainActivity.this, "An Error occured", FancyToast.ERROR, FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, true ).show ( );
            }
          break;
        case BROWSE_DEST:
          if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK )
            {
              txtFileDest.setText ( data.getData ( ).getPath ( ) );
            } else
            {
              FancyToast.makeText ( MainActivity.this, "An Error occured", FancyToast.ERROR, FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, true ).show ( );
            }
          break;
      }
  }
```